# Google Maps Engine Connector error

Tags: qgis, google-maps, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I have recently installed the Google Maps Engine Plugin for QGIS 2.0 and it doesn't seem to work. Whenever I click on the Log in button it pops up with:

**Google
Error:invalid_client
Bad request.**

**cookie_policy_enforce=false
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsengine https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
approval_prompt=auto
state=123456789
client_id=myemailaddress@googlemail.com**

I have uninstalled and re-installed the plugin several times but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I believe its to do with setting up a OAuth 2.0 Client ID through Google API access. QGIS Plugin settings for this app requires a 'Client ID' and 'Client Secret'.

Comment: This seems like it should be a bug report for the plugin devs. You can report on their Github page https://github.com/googlemaps/mapsengine-qgis-connector/issues.